# Label automatically change it's size, when I embed them in Stack

Tags: ios, swift, autolayout, uilabel, uistackview

I am having issue with auto-layout.

- I added 4 Labels to my storyboard and want them to be lined in centre of display
- I tried to embed them in Stack, but they automatically change their size and disappear from display.

What am I doing wrong?

Thank you for help.

Swift 3, XCode 8.2

[before](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ieQ32.png)
[after](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5yTIX.png)

Comment: You need to fix auto layout. Don't use fixe width. Add trailing, leading, top and bottom constraints. Change 'number of lines' to 0 in storyboard.

Comment: Hi, thanks, but I don't use fixed width. I've put constraints, but it doesn't help very much, because I don't see any label in simulator or if I rotate device: http://imgur.com/a/3tpEj

Comment: Have you entered text in label? and have you applied top bottom constraints? Upload a screen-shoot of your storyboard view.

Comment: Thanks, Saqib!!! When I entered test to Label, everything became alright! Wow! Really thank you!

Comment: Cheers. Happy coding.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What I do if working with stack views is. Drag from object library **vertical stack view**, place and add needed constraints

pin the stack view on the top, right and left. Let the bottom constraint unselected, so you can determine the variable width if your objects or its size in the stack view raises

[image]

If you drag the labels in the stack view, the edges of the stack view should highlight blue, this signalise that the label would places in the stack view. Drag the next label and bring it underneath the first one, you should see one vertical blue line, release and your second label is now in the stack view too.

[image]

If ready, select the stack view if not already selected in the document outline, go to the attribute inspector, and give the spacing between the lines, I make it to 40.

[image]

All the objects inside the stack view adjust themselves to the width of the stack view.
You can combine several stack views in one

[image]

I hope it could help you.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you should add Equal Width for every of this labels ?

Comment: Nope, unfortunately it makes no difference.